# Is there way to make a custom field type of 'Auto Number' a "hyperlink" on a dashboard?

Tags: dashboard

Is there way I can make a field on a dashboard a hyperlink that will take me to specific record without having to go to the overall report details to find it?

I have a custom field called 'Salesforce Generated ID' which is an auto-number on the opportunity that is displayed on the dashboard. Our users simply need the ability click that specific record to be navigated to the overall record page.

Yes, I know each SFDC record has its own unique (15 digit) id but this custom field is used for different purposes. Opportunity name (which is a hyperlink on dashboards) can't appear on the dashboard.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, the only way to create a custom hyperlink field would be to create another formula field with something along these lines:

```
HYPERLINK('/'+Id, AutoNumberField__c)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't display nicely on a dashboard, as you end up with something looking like this (which doesn't even link to the appropriate record):
[image]

It also appears that when you select drill down into the record detail, the only field that works on is the name field.

[image]